# Javascript Date.parse help

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datetime, parsing

I am using Javascript `Date.parse()` to check if a start time is after an end time.

The time in question is like this:

```
Date.parse("12:00pm") > Date.parse("9:30pm")
```

In Chrome this is coming up as false (as it should)

In IE it is incorrectly coming up as true.

The values Chrome see's are:

```
Thu Jul 22 2010 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Thu Jul 22 2010 21:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

The values IE sees are:

```
Thu Jul 22 12:00:00 EDT 2010
Thu Jul 22 09:30:00 EDT 2010
```

How can I make IE work correctly?

### update

OK this is only happening in IE7. Also I see now IE7 is not getting the am/pm which is stored in a SELECT box and retrieved via:

```
var startMerid = document.getElementById("start_time_ampm").options[document.getElementById("start_time_ampm").selectedIndex].value;
```

My select was like this:

```
<option>am</option>
```

but I changed to:

```
<option value="am">am</option>
```

and it now works.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing in? `Date.parse()` in IE8 gives me `NaN`, which is what I would expect in older versions because of how `Date.parse()` works in IE.  Of course, `NaN > NaN` will always be false.

Comment: If you look at my update I found the error, It was unrelated to the Date.parse and actually a problem in how I was receiving the AM/PM. In a case like this where the answer is unrelated to the original question... what is the SO best thing to do? Should I make that an answer and accept it.. or edit my question... or what?

Comment: if the solution was unrelated to the question, the best this is probably to just delete the question.  You can do this by clicking the delete link just below the tags.  Also, FYI `document.getElementById("start_time_ampm").value` would suffice, no need to get the `selectedIndex`

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the info, I clicked delete and it said "Sorry, this question cannot be deleted: too many existing answers, or upvoted/accepted answer" Since I think your answer best answers my original question I'll just mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for `Date.parse()` in IE state the following:

> If the 24-hour clock is used, **it is an error to specify "PM" for times later than 12 noon**. For example, "23:15 PM" is an error.

For a cross-browser solution, you should avoid *parse()* and parse the time string manually.  Alternatively, you could use a cross-browser library for parsing dates/times - [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) is a popular one.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you testing this on? IE8 correctly returns false for me.

Comment: IT was IE7 and the error was in how I was retrieving th AM/PM part of the string. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can not just pass a time to `Date.parse()`, as it is expecting a datestring.  If you flip the `>` in your code to a `<`, you'll notice it still returns `false`.  This is because `Date.parse()` is returning `NaN`.

Try this:

```
var a = new Date("January 1, 1970 12:00:00");
var b = new Date("January 1, 1970 21:30:00");

if (a > b) { alert(true); } else { alert(false); }
if (a < b) { alert(true); } else { alert(false); }
```